# Intercepting Javascript Before It's Run

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

In a firefox extension, how can I intercept nodes (specifically, script tags) from being run after they're added? I assume this is possible because extensions like NoScript and AdBlockPlus appear to do it. Is it possible from the javascript interface exposed to plugins?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about NoScript, but Adblock's main weapon is [nsIContentPolicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIContentPolicy).

You might also be interested in [onbeforescriptexecute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.onbeforescriptexecute). (And until the docs are updated with more info, see [the bug that added this feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587931).)